# Need password authentication while runing "systemctl stop .service"

Tags: centos, systemd, root, pam

I am looking for a way to add one more password authentication to run

```shell
systemctl stop abc.service
```

via root access.

I am using Rocky Linux.

I have no idea if it is even possible.  Please help.

Comment: This requires more details or clarity. Superficially, it sounds like you are asking for `sudo`?

Comment: well, root can do *anything* on you machine, including just killing programs (including services), and modifying kernel memory directly to stop scheduling a task. So, I'm not sure who's actually helped with setting up an extra barrier for root, which they inherently could work around. Sounds to me like you are allowing yourself or others to work as root when you really should not! Could you maybe explain your scenario a bit better, so that we understand which problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Im trying rocky 9 where i have blocking all usb storage access from OS but in KD workspace dolphin able to detect the MTP and PTP usb storage which im not able to block i tryed everying from internet noting worked for me so we use the USB-gaurd which worked and i want to protect that services from root im trying to put authenticator like after runing systemctl stop usbgaurd.services as root it should ask password or pin to again authenticate i know i sound odd asking this.